# Excel Invert VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have two lists, one from 1 to 10 the other from 1 to 5. I use the VLOOKUP to search in the large list the small list and it returns the values from 1 to 5 and from 6 to 10 it returns N/A.
The expession is like this : `=VLOOKUP(A:A;B:B;1;FALSE)`

I would really need it to return the values from 6 to 10 (the values that are not in the second list, but are in the first one). How can i do this? Doesn;t have to be on the same column or to use VLOOKUP. I would like a solution to return the values that are NOT the the small list.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I'll describe my test data:

Column A contains 1,10 in A1 - A10
Column B conatins 1,5 in B1 - B5
Column C contains the formula `VLOOKUP(A1,B1:B10,1,FALSE)` with the first argumnent updated as appropriately.

Using that formula I get 1,5 in C1 - C5 and N/A in C6-C10

If I change the formula to `=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,B1:B10,1,FALSE)),A1,"")` (again with the A1s updated appropiately), I get "" in C1-C5 and 6-10 in C6 - C10.

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes Sir, that is exactly what i needed, with the minor remark that in my case it is not working with , but with ; between the arguments. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Ion: That's because you're using a different language version of Excel than @Jon Egerton is.

Comment: @J-F: Interesting - is that a setting, or a difference between versions of Excel?